# Upgrade Windows Web Server 2008 R2 64 bits to Windows Server 2008 Standard remotely

Tags: windows-server-2008, remote-access, windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Upgrading Windows Server 2008](https://serverfault.com/questions/10299/upgrading-windows-server-2008)

How can I remotely upgrade a server running Windows Web Server 2008 R2 to Windows Server 2008 R2? Do any remote access tools allow me to do this?

Comment: Most modern server hardware already includes a remote access/lights out access system. What server hardware is this running on?

Answer (score 1):

What you'll be doing is "[migrating](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd759159.aspx)," not upgrading. To accomplish this you should have some kind of remote access card or KVM set up. Of course, you will need to back up your current setup.

With that said, it's perfectly valid to do bare-metal installs remotely. Remote access cards are worth every penny.